# SED substituir a mesma ocorrências maiúsculas e minusculas por algo

Tags: linux, shell-script, unix

Estou tentando substituir ocorrências "strings espectificas que aparecem no documento" por outro valor no caso '' nada;

tenho o seguinte trecho de código em shell script

```
mkdir NOVO
for script in *.sql
do 
    sed '/from/ s/fev_\|jan_//g' $script >> NOVO/$script
done
```

oque acontece é que só vai substituir as ocorrências "fev_" e "jan_" que estão em minusculo, porém existem ocorrencias em maiusculo como "FEV_" e até mesno "Fev_" como posso automatizar esse script para capturar todas essas ocorrências?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando de substituição do sed tem uma flag "I" que é utilizado para que a regex seja *case-insensitive*. Do man do sed:

I
i
**The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which makes sed match regexp in a case-insensitive manner.**

Então, vc pode alterar seu comando para:

`sed '/from/ s/fev_\|jan_//Ig' $script >> NOVO/$script`

Caso queira testar:

`cat teste.txt
linha
Linha
LINHA
lINHA
NADA`

`sed 's/linha/alterado/g' teste.txt
alterado
Linha
LINHA
lINHA
NADA`

`sed 's/linha/alterado/Ig' teste.txt
alterado
alterado
alterado
alterado
NADA`

Referências:

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917623/use-sed-with-ignore-case-while-adding-text-before-some-pattern

Comment: Entendi. Então poderia responder novamente a pergunta dessa forma? Usando o link como referência?